# How to take the first and last value from an arraylist inside an arraylist of arrylist using java

Tags: java, arraylist

How to take the first and last value from an arraylist inside an arraylist of arrylist and check the adjacent values of other arraylist values in java?

for example:

This is my arraylist of arraylist

```
[[1,0],[2,0],[3,3],[1,0,0]]
```

This arraylist size can be any thing not consatant and the values indside this arraylist will varies.

What I need here is [1,0] from this value it should take the first value and last value and need to check with all the other values from the arraylist of arraylist. If the adjacent values are same then it should store in a different place and need to display it.

I need a output like this:

```
group :0

1,0

1,0,0

group:1

2,0

group:3

3,3
```

If the first and last values are same it should go to one group and remaining different group and it need to display all the values.

This is the code I tried but i am very new to java. so my code is not that good .please help me to find this output.

```
  for (int a = 0; a < pattrn.size(); a++) {
        // System.out.println(pat.size());
        first = pattrn.get(a);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(first);
    String temp = first.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    System.out.println(temp);
    StringTokenizer firstvar = new StringTokenizer(temp, ", ");
    firstvalue = firstvar.nextToken();
    System.out.println("first value.." + firstvalue);
    while (firstvar.hasMoreTokens()) {
        lastvalue = firstvar.nextToken();
        System.out.println("last value.." + lastvalue);
    }
```

using this code I am not able to find this output.

Comment: please post a complete verifiable code. Something that doesnt give compile errors.

Comment: Sorry this is just a part of my large program and the code i put is a trial code I don't know exactly how to code it. I need the output in that format only so please help.

Comment: pattrn is the arraylist of arraylist values.first is an List<String> I am using all the variable here is arraylist or String no integer is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert your Lists into Strings.

The List class allows objects to be retrieved by indexes. So keeping in mind that indexes are 0 based for List in Java, you can do this:

```
List<List<Integer>> collection = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
//Some initialization to get to this: [[1,0],[2,0],[3,3],[1,0,0]]
//The [1,0] list can be retrieved by the index 0
List<Integer> list = collection.get(0);
//Then you can do the same thing on that list to get the first value 
Integer integer = list.get(0); //This will be 1
```

Then to get the last value in a list, you can use the `size()` method. This returns the size of the list. So in your case, that is 4. But remember that indexes start at 0, so to get the final element in a list, you use `size() - 1` as the index.

```
//Then the following line will give you the last List of [1,0,0]
List<Integer> list = collection.get( collection.size() - 1 );
//Then you can do the same thing on that list to get the last value
//The size here will be 3 of course as this is the [1,0,0] list
Integer integer = list.get( list.size() - 1 ); //This will be 0
```

Of course, you can combine these with loops of `int`s to loop though all of the indexes of a particular list and then do the comparisons.

I've written a program that does what you're looking for and placed it [here](https://ideone.com/vO9fxD). I've also tried to explain what I'm doing at each stage as it might make use of things you're not familiar with if you're new to Java.

**Edit: Eventual Solution**

The OP revealed in the comments that the elements in the lists must be Strings and not Integers as the items being processed may contain letters.

Also revealed was that the solution I had produced had a couple of issues. When testing it with the input `[[1,0],[2,0],[3,3],[1,0,0],[2,0],[2,0,0],[0,0],[1,2]]` it became apparent there were issues around the group numbers being assigned giving NullPointerExceptions during printing. Also, there was an issue where some lists would not be grouped appropriately due to concurrent modification of lists.

Having fixed the above issues, I produced [this version of my code](https://ideone.com/o4jJQ7) which fully solved this issue.

Comment: hello Dan the code you given is convincing one.But in this not only integer but string values will also come, so I have to generalize it and code so list<String> will be help full for me. And can you help me to find out the output for me that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: So the elements in the List of Lists are Strings? That's fine, you can change the elements to be Strings and not Integers, the retrieval by indexes will still work fine. The only other thing to change would be the comparison line as string comparison should be done with `.equals()` not `==`. I've done the changes and put them [here](https://ideone.com/x8Sw3X)

Comment: I'm confused by that question. You say your input is `an arraylist of arrylist` which looks like this `[[1,0],[2,0],[3,3],[1,0,0]]`. Now you say that your input isn't that and that its fixed size. The point of using Lists and Maps (and Collections generally) is that you don't need to worry about the size of them. The loops will also work no matter what the size of the collection is due to the use of the `size()` method.

Comment: hello Dan thanks your code it is working I got my first group but after printing second group:1 I got a null pointer exception.

Comment: Well, the groupsMap value ca't be null if it's printing something, so I'd have to gues that `groupsMap.get(i)` is returning null because the  map doesn't contain a group for that particular value of i. Could you possible provide your code? (on ideone would be fine)

Comment: I didn't change any of the code Dan just replaced the input as my input

Comment: Then perhaps your input is not as you expect it to be. Could you provide it, or how it is derived?

Comment: And Dan it will show more than one cluster as my input changes but always last 2,3 cluster its not showing.Sorry I couldn't put my code on ideone.

Comment: From your code I have taken only main part. Full code from there and I removed final keyword from all place because I didn't used it in my code.

Comment: Without your input I can't really help you in solving your issue. I advise debugging to the point where the NullPointerException occurs to find out what is null. From there you can find out what the problem is.

Comment: Dan can you do one favour, please add some more input values in your program in ideone like values [2,0],[2,0,0],[0,0],[1,2] and please run and check it. And add that link for ref. please..

Comment: My input is nothing but the values in arraylist of arraylist same as I mensioned in my question. Only change happening is there will be more number of value some time. Why I can't put my code is,if I'm putting it means I have to explain it to you and making you understand that will be complicated

Comment: With that input I found a couple of issues. 1) The groups were being added on the index values in the input list,  so if a list was removed from temp as it was grouped, it skipped an index. 2) I should remove all of the grouped lists after grouping, not during as that was making it skip some groups too. [Here's my revised solution](https://ideone.com/o4jJQ7).

Comment: Dan Thank you So much. I got it ! I don't know how to thank you exactly .you are a amazing programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, idk about the rest, but this is how you get the first and the last of each part of the array.

```
public static int[][] myArray = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
};
```

It's fairly simple to get the first and last, just run a loop over the array like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int first = myArray[i][0]; // first value
        int last = myArray[i][myArray[i].length - 1]; // last
        System.out.println("["+i+"]First: "+first+", Last: "+last+"");
    }
}
```

Output would be:

```
[0]First: 1, Last: 3
[1]First: 1, Last: 4
[2]First: 1, Last: 5
[3]First: 1, Last: 4
[4]First: 1, Last: 3
[5]First: 1, Last: 5
[6]First: 1, Last: 4
[7]First: 1, Last: 10
[8]First: 1, Last: 10
```

Hope this helped atleast some ^-^

EDIT: Also adding an array to an array list works the same way:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    static {
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 });
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
        myList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            int first = myList.get(i)[0]; // first value
            int last =  myList.get(i)[myList.get(i).length - 1]; // last
            System.out.println("["+i+"] First: "+first+", Last: "+last+"");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[0]First: 1, Last: 2
[1]First: 1, Last: 3
[2]First: 1, Last: 4
[3]First: 1, Last: 5
[4]First: 1, Last: 6
[5]First: 1, Last: 7
[6]First: 1, Last: 8
[7]First: 1, Last: 9
[8]First: 1, Last: 10
```

Comment: ofcourse with java8 you could probably do a nicer and more generic solution, sort of like you can do with scala.